# Getting unexpected row multiplication when selecting from combobox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am getting unexpected behavior after selecting a row in the list. I load the path to the folder from the drop-down list above the form, then I get the content in the selected folder (only directories, no files), then I select the file from the folders in the list with the mouse and get its full path to the console. This is necessary in order to use it in the future in a different form. But if I switch to another folder by selecting it from the list and selecting a directory from the new folder, I will get the path to the console 2 times. If I select again any folder in the drop-down list, even the one selected earlier, after selecting any item in this folder, I will get the path to it 3 times, and so on ad infinitum. Each download of the main folder from the drop-down list results in a "+1" to the path of the selected folder in the list

I don't understand why this is happening and how to deal with it?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '3.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *




mydir = 'C:/Users/Philipp_WORK/Desktop/Python/db/'

dirname = os.listdir(mydir)
print("this is the first list: " + str(dirname)) # for debug




def get_dirpaths(directory):

    dir_paths = [] 
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for dirs in directories:
            directory = os.path.join(root, dirs)
            dir_paths.append(directory)  
    return dir_paths 
global full_dirs_paths

full_dirs_paths = get_dirpaths(mydir)






# combine one DICT from two lists

global mydictfordbchoser


mydictfordbchoser = dict(zip(dirname, full_dirs_paths))

print("this is the COMBINED DICT: " + str(mydictfordbchoser)) # for debug






class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(350, 300)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 300))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 800))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupSelectFolder = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupSelectFolder.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.groupSelectFolder.setObjectName("groupSelectFolder")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupSelectFolder)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.dbChooser = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupSelectFolder)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.dbChooser.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.dbChooser.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.dbChooser.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)
        self.dbChooser.setObjectName("dbChooser")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dbChooser, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.listOfPosts = QtWidgets.QListView(self.groupSelectFolder)
        self.listOfPosts.setObjectName("listOfPosts")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listOfPosts, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupSelectFolder, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.dbChooser.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



        self.put_all_folder_in_combobox() # connection to function below
        
        self.dbChooser.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.show_posts_in_posts_window) # connection to function below






    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.groupSelectFolder.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Posts_will_Be_Here"))
        self.dbChooser.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "select_post"))
        self.dbChooser.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "select_post"))

        # my code starts here
  
    
    def put_all_folder_in_combobox(self):
        self.dbChooser.addItems(mydictfordbchoser) # mydictfordbchoser - global var



    def show_posts_in_posts_window(self, link_to_view):
        path = ''
        path = str(mydictfordbchoser[link_to_view])

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())

        self.listOfPosts.setModel(self.model)
        self.listOfPosts.setRootIndex(self.model.index(path))


        self.listOfPosts.clicked.connect(self.get_path_from_listOfPosts)
        

        print(path) # for debug



    def get_path_from_listOfPosts(self):
        index = self.listOfPosts.currentIndex()
        filepath = self.model.filePath(index)
        print(str(filepath) + "/") # why here i get multiplication rows as time as i switch groupbox ?






if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

some pics for better understanding (cause my english not perfect)

[programm starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qloGq.jpg)

[load main folder and click from 1 to 10 folder once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWHKG.jpg)

[change directory to empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I64Y.jpg)

[back to first directory again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN6fQ.jpg)

[click from one to 4 folder once and get this strange behavior (each folder printed to console  x3 times)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Zuz.jpg)

Comment: move the line `self.listOfPosts.clicked.connect(self.get_path_from_listOfPosts)` from `Ui_MainWindow.show_posts_in_posts_window` to `Ui_MainWindow.setupUi`. You only need to connect the signal once. As it is now you create an extra connection every time you choose something in the combo box.

Comment: @Heike Thanks, It really worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Qt signal connections behave almost as callbacks, they are not unique: you can connect more slots/functions, including *the same* function more than once.

Consider the following:

```
        self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.someFunction)
        self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.someFunction)

    def someFunction(self):
        print('clicked')
```

The result will be that "clicked" will be printed *twice* everytime the button is clicked.

The problem with your code is that you're connecting the `clicked` signal of `self.listOfPosts` *everytime* the `dbChooser` index is changed.

The general suggestion is to make all connections in the `__init__` of classes, or only when you're sure that the function making the connection is only run once for the lifespan of the sender (the signal emitter) or receiver (the called function).

Since in your case `get_path_from_listOfPosts` will be called only when a valid index is selected, there's no risk of getting any exception if the model is still empty, so just move the connection in the `setupUi`:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...
        self.listOfPosts.clicked.connect(self.get_path_from_listOfPosts)
```

That said, some important suggestions:

1. [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) already has the clicked index as its argument, there's no need to use `index = self.listOfPosts.currentIndex()`:

```
    def get_path_from_listOfPosts(self, index):
        filepath = self.model.filePath(index)
```

2. there's no need to create a new model everytime: set the model in `setupUi` and just call `setRootPath()` when needed; besides the fact that creating a new instance of the same model is pointless, QFileSystemModel is a pretty complex model that requires more resources (which also provide a caching mechanism that would become useless if recreated): you should always reuse the same instance whenever possible;
3. globals should always be avoided unless you *really* know what they should be used for and how they behave; the general rule is that if you're using them it's because there's something wrong in your object structure;
4. as clearly stated in the header of the file, you should **never** edit files generated by pyuic unless you **really** know what you're doing: modifying those files is generally considered bad practice; read how to properly use those files in the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);